# Issue in printing dictionary content

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the below code, am assigning application name to the process id (hard coded), Ex: In the below code 1468 is the process id and outlook is the process name. In the hard coded values have entered cpu related information, for each pid. 
Here i want to replace process id with process name, and should get the cpu related information for the corresponding process name output as shown in the values dictionary.

Expected output

```
outlook: [
    233.625,
    336.15625,
    43791.0,
    168.21875,
    94.859375
], 
chrome: [
    3713.625,
    3396.15625,
    36791.0,
    628.21875,
    48.859375
],
command prompt:[
    3713.625,
    396.15625,
    3791.0,
    628.21875,
    48.859375
]
```

Actual output:

```
3796
12972
1468
process name for this pid outlook
{3796: [3713.625, 396.15625, 3791.0, 628.21875, 48.859375], 12972: [3713.625, 3396.15625, 36791.0, 628.21875, 48.859375], 1468: [233.625, 336.15625, 43791.0, 168.21875, 94.859375]}
```

Code:

```
import os, platform, subprocess, re 
import sys
import psutil
import itertools 
import json

#if __name__ == "__main__" :
if True:
    dict = {'1468 ': 'outlook', '12972':'chrome', '3796': 'command prompt'}

    values ={
                1468 : [
                    233.625,
                    336.15625,
                    43791.0,
                    168.21875,
                    94.859375
                ], 
                12972: [
                    3713.625,
                    3396.15625,
                    36791.0,
                    628.21875,
                    48.859375
                ],
                3796:[
                    3713.625,
                    396.15625,
                    3791.0,
                    628.21875,
                    48.859375
                ]
            }
class pretty:
    def printf(self, json_object):
        print(json.dumps(json_object, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=
(',', ': ')))

    def comparision(self):
        for iter in values.keys():
            print (iter) 
        for proc in psutil.process_iter():
            if iter == proc.pid:
               #print(iter)
                print("process name for this pid" +" "+proc.name())
                if iter == proc.pid:
                    print(values)

pretty.comparision("")
```

Please help me in resolving this, am a newbie to python

Comment: What's the purpose of `if True:` and the `pretty` class?

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using `dict` and `values` as variable names since they are `dictionary` keywords, and using them as variables would lead to unexpected results:

Use:

```
dict1 = {'1468 ': 'outlook', '12972':'chrome', '3796': 'command prompt'}
values1 ={
    1468 : [
        233.625,
        336.15625,
        43791.0,
        168.21875,
        94.859375
    ], 
    12972: [
        3713.625,
        3396.15625,
        36791.0,
        628.21875,
        48.859375
    ],
    3796:[
        3713.625,
        396.15625,
        3791.0,
        628.21875,
        48.859375
    ]
}

>>> res = {}
>>> for key, value in dict1.items():
...    res[dict1[key]] = values1[int(key)]
... 
>>> res
{'chrome': [3713.625, 3396.15625, 36791.0, 628.21875, 48.859375], 'outlook': [233.625, 336.15625, 43791.0, 168.21875, 94.859375], 'command prompt': [3713.625, 396.15625, 3791.0, 628.21875, 48.859375]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do

```
for key in dict:
    print (dict[key], ":", values[int(key)])
```

I can add more explanation if that's all that's needed.

Comment: Hi thank you, but it should display in json format .. but when i add preety class i'm getting error like                                                 pretty.printf(dict[key], ":", values[int(key)])
TypeError: printf() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: @patricks: but it should display in json format .. but when i add preety class i'm getting error like pretty.printf(dict[key], ":", values[int(key)]) TypeError: printf() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given –

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {'1468': 'outlook', '12972':'chrome', '3796': 'command prompt'}
values ={1468 : [233.625,336.15625,43791.0,168.21875,94.859375],
12972: [3713.625,3396.15625,36791.0,628.21875,48.859375],
3796:[3713.625,396.15625,3791.0,628.21875,48.859375]}
new_dict={}

for k in values.keys():
    new_dict[dict[str(k)]] = str(values[k])

print new_dict # this would give you a dictionary
```

Comment: Thank you keval, but i should get the result in json format.. so pls tel how to solve that

Comment: dictionary is same as json this case  ,since you don't have nested keys.